# How to assign text from object to marker with same index and show relevant text after click to relevant marker? (Openlayers map)

Tags: javascript, events, indexing, javascript-objects, openlayers

I use OpenLayers map and I would like to get some text from *var informations* after click to marker. I think thant I need to have "general" function about singleclick in cycle for, because I need do it for each index [i]. But If I click to some marker I don´t see any information.

I tried to move "general" function to down before *console.table(window.phpdata.markers)*. When I run it, I can see last text from "informations" after click on each marker --> there isn´t any problem with getting data from databases.

(This isn´t required result because I don´t want to see last marker. I would like to see relevant text from informations for relevant marker. So with same index [i].

What to do for this result? Thank´s

```
Object.defineProperty(window.phpdata, "markers", {value: <?php echo !empty($list) ? json_encode($list) : 'null'; ?>, writable: false, configurable: false});
var base = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [base],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-74.0061,40.712]), zoom: 2
    })
});

var vectors = new ol.source.Vector({});

if(window.phpdata.markers && window.phpdata.markers.length > 0) {
        var data = window.phpdata.markers;

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var informations = data[i].info;



        var marker = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
                ol.proj.fromLonLat([Number(data[i].lng), Number(data[i].lat)])
                ),
                });

                marker.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                src: 'dot.png'
                }))
                }));

                vectors.addFeature(marker);

                marker.on('singleclick', function (event) {            //general function to move..
                     if (map.hasFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel) === true) {
                        document.getElementById("www").innerHTML=informations;
                     } else {
                         overlay.setPosition(undefined);
                         closer.blur();
                     }
                 });                                            // //to there

        }

        var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectors,
        });

        map.addLayer(layer);
}


document.getElementById('myposition').innerText = "click to map and get coordinates here";
map.on('singleclick', event => {
  const coordinate = ol.proj.toLonLat(event.coordinate);
  //const innerText = `Lon: ${coordinate[0].toFixed(4)}, Lat: ${coordinate[1].toFixed(4)}`;
  const innerText = `${coordinate[0].toFixed(4)}, ${coordinate[1].toFixed(4)}`;
  document.getElementById('myposition').innerText = innerText;
});


map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel) ? 'pointer' : '';
});


console.table(window.phpdata.markers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Features do not have click events.  You need to check if there are features where you click the map.  You can add the info as a property to the feature and use get() to display it.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var marker = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
            ol.proj.fromLonLat([Number(data[i].lng), Number(data[i].lat)])
        ),
        info: data[i].info
    });
}

....
....

map.on('click', function(evt) {
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function(feature) {
            return feature;
        });
    if (feature) {
        document.getElementById("www").innerHTML = feature.get('info');
        ....
    };
});
```